# ionic/AngularJs transfer data between views

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to transfer data between two views.  I followed the example on http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/sharing-data-between-views/ but can't seem to get it right.

essentially my app.js is:

```
    .state('friends', {
        url: '/friends',
        templateUrl: 'templates/friends.html',
        controller: 'FriendsCtrl'
    })

    .state('friend-detail', {
        url: '/friends/:friendId',
        templateUrl: 'templates/friend-detail.html',
        controller: 'FriendDetailCtrl'
    });
```

In friends.html I have a list of my friends and I am trying to pass the id to friend-detail.html.  Here is the content of friends.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-avatar" ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-href='#/friends/{{friend.id}}'>
      <img ng-src="{{friend.face}}">
      <h2>{{friend.name}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and I am looking for `friend.id` or `friend.name` in friend-detail.html. I am able to use `{{friend.id}}` in friends.html to test and it's working but can't get to new page.

Here is my list just incase:

```
.factory('Friends', function() {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  // Some fake testing data
  // Some fake testing data
  var friends = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Ben Sparrow',
    notes: 'Enjoys drawing things',
    face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/514549811765211136/9SgAuHeY.png'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Max Lynx',
    notes: 'Odd obsession with everything',
    face: 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/11214?v=3&s=460'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Andrew Jostlen',
    notes: 'Wears a sweet leather Jacket. I\'m a bit jealous',
    face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491274378181488640/Tti0fFVJ.jpeg'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Adam Bradleyson',
    notes: 'I think he needs to buy a boat',
    face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/479090794058379264/84TKj_qa.jpeg'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Perry Governor',
    notes: 'Just the nicest guy',
    face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491995398135767040/ie2Z_V6e.jpeg'
  }];


  return {
    all: function() {
      return friends;
    },
    get: function(friendId) {
      // Simple index lookup
      return friends[friendId];
    }
  }
})
```

and here are the controllers:

FriendsCtrl:

```
.controller('FriendsCtrl', function($scope, $state, Friends) {
    $scope.friends = Friends.all();
});
```

NewTransfersCtrl:

```
.controller('NewTransfersCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Friends) {
    $scope.friend = Friends.get($stateParams.friendId);
})
```

Comment: you should be using `ng-href` rather than `href` when your link includes an expression.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref#!/

Comment: i actually tried `ng-href` first but it didn't work.

Comment: So what does "can't get to new page" mean? Is the URL wrong? Do you get an error? Does the button not click?  More context is needed

Comment: oh sure.  so as you can see i have a list of the friends.  when i click on it, the item clicks (since i can see it highlight), but nothing happens.  it's supposed to go the **friend-detail.html** page but that doesn't load

Comment: hi @Claies any idea why it's still not working?

Answer (score 0):

See sample here : http://codepen.io/aaronksaunders/pen/gbWgQe?editors=101

basically you should be checking for the `stateParams.id` to get the id being passed on the URL. It would be easier to show you what is missing if you provided more code.

Comment: Hi @AaronSaunders any idea? pretty much added all of the code for it. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: just create a functioning code pen and send the link... there is no code here for the detail view?